# How to end mp3 tasks from background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I have countdowntimer where I have some mp3 files which plays always after brake and round (I am making boxing countdown) and I would like to make "end: button. But my problem relies on that when I am using this function

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main5Activity.class);
                    Main3Activity.this.finishAffinity();
                    startActivity(intent);
```

the app redirects to 5activity but In background I am still hears this mp3 ring when round ends. I tried `finish();` , `finishAffinity();`. `finishActivity(0); but it didn't help. I treid`                         System.exit(0); too but I don't wont to exit whole my app only from this activity and end all tasks whcih will not to run in the background.

i don't know that i include in my question all important thing. Tell me if not and then I will edit my question

EDIT

```
 timerodrundy = new CountDownTimer(dłrundy, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





                    tv1.setText("Runda");
                    tv5.setText( (round_count1[0] + 1) + "/" + finalNum_rounds1);
                    mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                    updatetext();







                }



                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (licz ==1){
                        tv3.setText("Koniec");
                    }
                    tv1.setText("Przerwa");
                    tv2.setText("");





                    MediaPlayer r1=MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rinknkw);
                    r1.start();
                    if (licz > 1) {

                        round_count[0]++;
                        if (round_count[0] < finalNum_rounds) {

                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    start();

                                }
                            }, dłprzerwy);
                        }


                    }
                    if (round_count[0] == finalNum_rounds){
                        tv3.setText("Koniec");
                    }
                    if (tv3.getText().toString().equals("Koniec")){
                        tv1.setText("");
                    }







                }
            }.
                    start();
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are playing the .mp3, note that you need to call the player?.stop() player?.reset() player?.release() on onstop function of the activity

Comment: do you use ExoPlayer? If yes just  call player.stop() before startActivity(intent)

Comment: I eddited my question'

Comment: In on finish I ussed Media player.create